# Background color on body, with an div on top of it

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

My body uses a color gradient, but on top of it, I want to have a wrapper around the whole web page (because of vertical/horizontal align). However, because of this div, the background can't be seen anymore. I tried to solve this problem by using RGBA and Opacity, but neither of them worked.

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ItsKasper_/cnpczafL/
Code:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='list'>
    <p>test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:
Couldn't get the CSS to correctly show.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` sizes with content and as the `wrapper`, the only direct child, is positioned absolute, its height becomes `0`, but the `html` is the full viewport

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnpczafL/1/)

```
html {
    background: #457fca; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* Standard syntax */
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

If you give the `body` a height, `height: 100vh;`, it would work as well

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnpczafL/2/)

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #457fca; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* Standard syntax */
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

And since the `wrapper` has the size of the viewport, you could of course set the background on it

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnpczafL/3/)

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #457fca; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #457fca, #5691c8); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: I now have a background, but it's a single color. I have updated my fiddle, so you can see the result yourself. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ItsKasper Link to your updated fiddle? ... and the gradient works, I changed one color so it clearly shows: https://jsfiddle.net/cnpczafL/6/

Comment: Okay, it did work. Apparently the colors aren't distinct enough. It works now. Thanks!